# Split string with strange pattern

Tags: regex

I have a string

```
"foo:bar rty:qwe magic qwe"
```

I need to split it into `["foo:bar", "rty:qwe magic qwe"]`

My problem is that there can be many words separated by space on the right part(after":")

Can't imagine such regular expression... Can someone help?

Comment: Just 1 language please. And can you post some more sample input? It's not pretty clear how exactly you want to split given the current input.

Comment: What language? Please don't just tag the question with multiple unrelated languages.

Comment: I really didn't care about the language cause regexps are almost identicall. Even the given solutions don't use regexps they are presented almost in all languages/libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just split before the next key, using a lookahead. As Perl code:

```
say qq/"$_"/ for split /\s+(?=\w+:)/, "foo:bar rty:qwe magic qwe baz:qux";
```

Output:

```
"foo:bar"
"rty:qwe magic qwe"
"baz:qux"
```

Unlike other answers that solve the problem by limiting the number of resulting fragments (I can do this too: `split " ", $string, 2`), this works for arbitrary numbers of `key: value value` sequences.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, there is no need to use a regex. Just `split`.

```
>>> "foo:bar rty:qwe magic qwe".split(None, 1)
['foo:bar', 'rty:qwe magic qwe']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood your question right, but this does what it should for your given example. The solution is in Java:

```
String str = "foo:bar rty:qwe magic qwe";
String[] arr = str.split(" ", 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

prints

`[foo:bar, rty:qwe magic qwe]`

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you can use the [`split()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function and specify a limit:

```
$s = "foo:bar rty:qwe magic qwe";
@result = split(' ',$s,2);
```